# How summarise values in group_by in R by using quasiquotation?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data table

```
  df_demo <- data.table(
    year = c(2021, 2022, 2022, 2023),
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(5, 6, 7, 8))
```

I would like to group by "year" and average values per other columns for any number and names of columns.

Here is how it can be made with "fixed" number of column names

```
  df_demo %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(
      x = mean(x),
      y = mean(y)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Here is how I would like to have by using R Quasiquotation

```
  # List of columns
  list_columns <- c("x", "y")
  
  # Replacement
  for(column_i in list_columns) {        

    column_i <- sym(column_i)

    df_demo %>% 
      group_by(year) %>% 
      summarise(
        !!column_i = mean(!!column_i)) %>% 
      ungroup()
  }
```

But this not works for the left side variable "!!column_i" because I would like to keep the same name of the column.

Any bits of help are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: why not replacing your for loop with   ``summarise(across(...,~ mean(.x)))`` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the walrus operator `:=` if you are using quasiquotation for the left hand side of the assignment:

```r
for(column_i in list_columns) {        
  
  column_i <- sym(column_i)
  
  df_demo %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(
      !!column_i := mean(!!column_i)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    print()
}
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    year     x
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2021   1  
#> 2  2022   2.5
#> 3  2023   4  
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    year     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2021   5  
#> 2  2022   6.5
#> 3  2023   8
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there are a few workarounds for this issue. The idea is to use variable column names in `summarise` and the challenge is how we are going to manage the naming in the function which is normally defined as `summarise(name_of_col=mean(column_name))`. Let's say we have the same data set as you defined:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df_demo <- data.table(
  year = c(2021, 2022, 2022, 2023),
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = c(5, 6, 7, 8))
```

The idea for tackling the problem is easy. Give the variable column to `summarise` with a fixed name (`m` is this case) and then use `rename()` function to rename it based on the column name. Also, there are two options for defining variables in `summarise` as below:

### 1. Using `!!(column_i)`

```
# List of columns
list_columns <- c("x", "y")
# define an empty list
df_mean <- list()
# Loop through the columns using !!(column_i)
for (column_i in list_columns) {
  column_i <- sym(column_i)
  df_mean[[column_i]] <- df_demo %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(m=mean(!!enquo(column_i))) %>% 
    rename(!!(column_i) := m)  
}
df_mean
$x
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2021   1  
2  2022   2.5
3  2023   4  

$y
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2021   5  
2  2022   6.5
3  2023   8
```

### 2. Using `!!enquo(column_i)`

```
# List of columns
list_columns <- c("x", "y")
# define an empty list
df_mean <- list()
# Loop through the columns using !!enquo(column_i)
for (column_i in list_columns) {
  column_i <- sym(column_i)
  df_mean[[column_i]] <- df_demo %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(m=mean(!!enquo(column_i))) %>% 
    rename(!!enquo(column_i) := m)  
}
df_mean
$x
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2021   1  
2  2022   2.5
3  2023   4  

$y
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2021   5  
2  2022   6.5
3  2023   8
```

Or you can simply bind the results using `left_join` function as below (here, `year` column is the column in common between different outputs):

```
# define an empty vector
df_bind <- tibble(year=unique(df_demo$year))
# Loop through the columns
for (column_i in list_columns) {
  column_i <- sym(column_i)
  df_mean <- df_demo %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(m=mean(!!enquo(column_i))) %>% 
    rename(!!(column_i) := m)  
  # bind the results
  df_bind <- left_join(df_bind,df_mean,by='year')
}
df_bind
# A tibble: 3 × 3
   year     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2021   1     5  
2  2022   2.5   6.5
3  2023   4     8
```

I Hope it Helps.

Comment: The [official guide](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) does not suggest using `sym` any more. It would be better to suggest the more current recommendation to use the `.data` pronoun. Plus the `:=` has been around a while for setting column names so it would be better to suggest that then the extra `rename`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using column names as strings, the corrent recommended way to do this is with the `.data` pronoun. And if you want to dynamcially name columns, you want to use the `:=` operator with the syntax from the `glue` package. So you would want

```
for(column_i in list_columns) {        
  
  df_demo %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(
      "{column_i}" := mean(.data[[column_i]])) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

Be sure to check out the [programming with dplyr guide](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) where these topics are discussed.